# Evaluating obfuscated JavaScript variable declaration

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a malicious JavaScript code that has some obfuscated variable declarations that go like this:

```
var saki8haveTogether48 = {
    st9a: function (abert, z, n, m) {
        return String["fromChar" + "Co" + "" + "de"]((+'111') + 5)
    },
    revie5: '123'
} ['st9a'](function () {
    return true;
}, 0, 0, 1) + {
    marbl8a: function (abert, z, n, m) {
        return String["fromChar" + "Co" + "" + "de"]((+'109') + 5)
    },
    studi8: '95'
} ['marbl8a'](function () {
    return true;
}, 0, 0, 1) + {
    meta9a: function (abert, z, n, m) {
        return String["fromChar" + "Co" + "" + "de"]((+'92') + 5)
    },
    brig6: '103'
} ['meta9a'](function () {
    return true;
}, 0, 0, 1) + {
    works9a: function (abert, z, n, m) {
        return String["fromChar" + "Co" + "" + "de"]((+'105') + 5)
    },
    this94: '100'
} ['works9a'](function () {
    return true;
}, 0, 0, 1) + {
    whi5a: function (abert, z, n, m) {
        return String["fromChar" + "Co" + "" + "de"]((+'110') + 5)
    },
    pre8: '121'
} ['whi5a'](function () {
    return true;
}, 0, 0, 1);
```

There are over 50 such variable declarations, hence I intend to have some automated way to do this.

My approach is to mark certain portions of the script which I want to evaluate by using the eval() function. After evaluating it, I want to replace the obfuscated code with what I have evaluated. The snippet above is one such example.

However when I evaluate the right side of this variable declaration, I get an error saying:

`SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name`

My question is: Is there any way to evaluate just the right side of the statement?

Comment: Sure – if you are willing to modify the code slightly, so that the requirement the error message mentioned is fulfilled … (Whether that will lead to anything, and not just cause further errors, would be a different question.)

Comment: If you have an anonymous function and want to execute it you can make it self-executing by adding some extra parentheses: `function() { ... }` becomes `(function() { ... })()`. If you don't want to execute it you need to assign it, otherwise the code will do nothing.

Comment: I think your issue is the first `{` is interpreted as being a block rather than an object if you remove the rest. Just wrap the whole thing inside `()` and that should work.

Comment: @BaliBalo That does indeed fix it.